# XalanTransformer output to standard out?

Tags: c++, xalan

Using [Xalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xalan) I have an XalanTransformer that produces output to a file. How do I make it go to standard out instead?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <xalanc/Include/PlatformDefinitions.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xalanc/XalanTransformer/XalanTransformer.hpp>
constexpr auto REPORT_FILE {"report.html"};
....
std::stringstream xml_doc; xml_doc << ....;
std::stringstream style_sheet; style_sheet << ....;
XALAN_USING_XERCES(XMLPlatformUtils)
XALAN_USING_XALAN(XalanTransformer)
XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
XalanTransformer::initialize();
XalanTransformer transformer;
transformer.transform(xml_doc, style_sheet, REPORT_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

if (transformer.transform(xml_doc, style_sheet, std::cout) != 0)
```

> The input source and result target can be a file name, a stream or a root node.

```
int xalanc::XalanTransformer::transform (
    const XSLTInputSource &theInputSource,
    const XalanCompiledStylesheet *heCompiledStylesheet,
    const XSLTResultTarget &theResultTarget)
```

[int xalanc::XalanTransformer::transform](https://apache.github.io/xalan-c/api/classxalanc_1_1XalanTransformer.html#a4dde51ccb0e8dda90a79bb5ee1214cfc)

The question used a file name the result target. The answer uses a stream, `std:cout`.

> The global objects std::cout and std::wcout control output to a stream buffer of implementation-defined type (derived from std::streambuf), associated with the standard C output stream stdout.

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com)  [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)

Comment: Some explanations would benefit the OP.